# Highchart javascript chart example not working

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I am beginner on front end and don't know much about HTML/CSS and Javascript. I am trying to run below code example from http://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/your-first-chart URL but for some reason it is not working on my machine when I open this html file on my browser. It doesn't display the chart where as it should display the chart here right? I am sure I am making some silly mistake here.

Can you please help and see what is wrong here? I have just copied what I see on the example on the website.

Please help.

```
    <head> 
      <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px"></div>

    <script>
    $(function () {

        $.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?', function (data) {
            // Create the chart
            $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {


                rangeSelector : {
                    selected : 1
                },

                title : {
                    text : 'AAPL Stock Price'
                },

                series : [{
                    name : 'AAPL',
                    data : data,
                    tooltip: {
                        valueDecimals: 2
                    }
                }]
            });
        });

    });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your script `JQUERY` should be loaded first then the rest .

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px"></div>

<script>
$(function () {
    $.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?', function (data) {
        // Create the chart
        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
            rangeSelector : {
                selected : 1
            },
            title : {
                text : 'AAPL Stock Price'
            },
            series : [{
                name : 'AAPL',
                data : data,
                tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 2
                }
            }]
        });
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Nice. It works after making that change. Thank you @Suchit.